# Web deploy powershell cmdlet Backup

Tags: powershell, deployment, backup, webdeploy, powershell-cmdlet

I want to use `Backup-WDApp` web deploy powershell cmdlet to backup an iisApp to my windows machine from another windows machine. I want the backup to be saved in a location mentioned by me.

Please add how to mention folder location to the following cmdlet

```
$list = @('\\Default Web Site\\SendSMS_Img\\1.jpeg')  

Backup-WDApp "Default web site/SendSMS_Img" 
     -SourcePublishSettings "D:\Web Deploy\SendSMS.publishsettings" 
     @{encryptPassword='pass@123'} –SkipFileList $list
```

Also, I want the backup to skip a jpeg file which is in `C:\Users\username\System.Collections.Hashtable\MachineName_IisApp_Default web site_SendSMS_Img_20130813172754.zip\Content\Default web site\SendSMS_Img`. My cmdlet isn't skipping the jpeg file. I guess the regular exp is wrong.

Comment: If $list is supposed to contain a regular expression, you should probably either manually escape the metacharacters (\ and .) or use `$list = @([regex]::escape('\Default Web Site\SendSMS_Img\1.jpeg'))`.

Comment: Got answer `Backup-WDApp "Default web site/SendSMS_Img" "D:\Web Deploy\Backup_iisApp_SendSMS_Img" -SourcePublishSettings "D:\Web Deploy\SendSMS.publishsettings"`created the zip file in the location desired by me.

Answer (score 0):

This works with ignoring 1.jpeg in the root-Directory of the application. I added some additonal excludes for reference.

```
$application = 'Default web site/SendSMS_Img'
$workingDir = 'desired FilePath'
$fileIgnoreList = @('\\1.jpeg','\\*.aspx','\\foo.bar','\\*.publishproj')
$folderIgnoreList = @('\\bin','\\images','\\foo','\\bar')
Add-PSSnapin WDeploySnapin3.0 
Backup-WDApp $application  -SkipFileList $fileIgnoreList -SkipFolderList $folderIgnoreList -Output $workingDir
```